# How can I change the data arrangement in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data that, when imported to my notebook, is shown in the form:

`list = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}`

I want to transform this into:

`list = {{{1,2},3},{{4,5},6},{{7,8},9},{{10,11},12}}`

How can I do this?

Comment: My intent is make the data in a form that permite me do a multi-dimensional interpolation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Method 1 - No `Map`

With no `Map`s.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
Transpose@{list[[;; , ;; 2]], list[[;; , 3]]}
```

> {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}}

## Method 2 - `Apply`

Not technically `Map`, but still iterating.

```
{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ list
```

> {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}}

Answer (score 11):

Another way

```
list /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {{x, y}, z}
```

> {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}}

Answer (score 8):

```
Through[{Most, Last}[#]] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do `Map[{Most[#], Last[#]} &, list]` to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 7):

also you can do

```
lst = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
{#[[;; -2]], #[[-1]]} & /@ lst
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also possible (if you like to view things as matrices)

```
a = Map[List, lst[[All, {1, -2}]]]
b = lst[[All, -1]]
MapThread[Append, {a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<s>8 more different</s> 6 more ways could be possible.

Answer (score 7):

Using **SequenceCases**:

```
SequenceCases[list, {x_}:>{Most@x, Last@x}]
```

Answer (score 6):

A rule-based approach:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
list /. {x__?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {{x}, y}
```

A simple `Table`-based approach:

```
Table[{list[[kk, 1 ;; 2]], list[[kk, 3]]}, {kk, 1, Length@list}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
BlockMap[Join,Riffle[list[[All,;;2]],list[[All,3]]],{2}]

(* {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}} *)
```

**In addition**

```
Fold[List,#]&/@list

(* {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}} *)
```

**Also**

```
MapThread[{{#1,#2},#3}&,Transpose[list]]

(* {{{1,2},3},{{4,5},6},{{7,8},9},{{10,11},12}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Drop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop.html) and [`Append`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) are sometimes useful. The following works:

```
Map[Append[{Drop[#, -1]}, Last[#]] &, list]
```

Comment: Instead of using Drop, use Most. It is clearer and shorter

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html). All of the following work:

```
Map[{Flatten[Partition[#, 2]], #[[-1]]} &, list]

Map[{Flatten[Partition[#, 2]], #[[3]]} &, list]

Map[{First[Partition[#, 2]], #[[-1]]} &, list]

Map[{First[Partition[#, 2]], #[[3]]} &, list]

Map[{First[Partition[#, 2]], Last[#]} &, list]
```

Answer (score 4):

The well known IA told me, with the exact question as prompt :

```
In[1]:= list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
Out[1]= {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}

In[2]:= transformedList = Map[{Take[#, 2], Last[#]} &, list]
Out[2]= {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}}
```

And it works. I never touched mathics before. It's not (so much) ironic but to remember that new fact.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
```

With `Comap` (new in 14.0)

```
Comap[{Most, Last}] /@ list
```

{{{1, 2}, {3}}, {{4, 5}, {6}}, {{7, 8}, {9}}, {{10, 11}, {12}}}

With `TakeList` (new in 11.2)

```
TakeList[#, {2, 1}] & /@ list
```

{{{1, 2}, {3}}, {{4, 5}, {6}}, {{7, 8}, {9}}, {{10, 11}, {12}}}

With `Query` (new in 10.0)

```
Query[All, {Most, Last}] @ list
```

{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}, {{10, 11}, 12}}